# Can you store cookies if you create a new window on the main one?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a google styled login with a popup window, but I need to save cookies for information of the user and other things, is that possible?

This is the code to open the window(popup)
The site that it opens isn't the same as the main.

```
const openwindow = () => {
  window.open("https://chome.vercel.app/login", "", "width=400,height=500");
}
```

Comment: Cookies are tied to the domain, as long as the domain is same, there shouldn't be an issue opening a new window

Answer (score 1):

"window.open()" method return Window object. You can use it for setting any value.

But opened domain should be the same as the old page domain. In another way, you can not change anything, it is a secure requirements.